Canvas draw line is blurred even if devicePixelRatio (DPR) is 1
is anyone able to explain why in DPR==1 line at whole pixel is still blurred?
https://codepen.io/Ondej-Spilka/pen/LYvrpby
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(100, 50);
context.lineTo(100, 150);
context.stroke();

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(120.5, 50);
context.lineTo(120.5, 150);
context.stroke();


Thanks in advance!

Does this answer your question? Can I turn off antialiasing on an HTML  element?

The blurryness doesn't have to do anything with the DPR here.
When you think about the grid of pixels on a canvas, including the concept of sub-pixels, you will realize that the coordinate of (0, 0) is not the pixel in the top left corner, but actually the top left corner of that pixel.
This means that a vertical line of width 1 on the coordinate x = 100 doesn't have its center in the middle of the pixel with index 100, but on its left edge.
You are drawing a 1 pixel width vertical line on the coordinate x = 100, hence the line is drawn spanning from x = 99.5 to 100.5, in order to be centered around the x = 100 coordinate like you wanted. This means coloring both pixels in columns x = 99 and x = 100 at half the intensity, resulting in the blurry appearance.
Your second vertical line moves the center +0.5 over. Its center is 120.5, so the line horizontally spans from x = 120 to x = 121, which is equivalent to coloring the full width of the pixel at index 120 and doesn't appear blurry.
You will see that by setting context.lineWidth = 2; at the beginning, the line at x = 100 would appear sharp (since it now spans from x = 99 to x = 101) while the line at x = 120.5 appears blurry (since it spans from x = 119.5 to x = 121.5).
Note that this is caused by the odd line width, not the start and end coordinates. Offsetting the x coordinates by 0.5 works for a vertical line, because it makes the 1px wide line overlap exactly with the pixel column of your screen. For a horizontal line, you would need to offset the y coordinate.
In general:

If you are only ever working with vertical lines of odd width, you can add a translate(0.5, 0) to the whole canvas to get crisp lines.
If you are only ever working with horizontal lines of odd width, you can translate(0, 0.5) to get crisp lines.
If you have horizontal and vertical lines of odd width, you can still translate(0.5, 0.5) to get mostly crisp lines, at the expense of blurry line endings.
If you have mixed even and odd line width, translating won't help at all, because that would just shift the problem to all lines of even width appearing blurry then.


Thanks for comment, but sounds to me a bit overcomplicated for simple pixel grid system.
Let's assume pixel [0,0], line width 1, drawline(0,0,0,2)
Line has to occupy pixels [0,0], [0,1], [0,2], simple as that.
comment - on high DPI retina display this works as expected. The problem occurs on wide  21:9 screen.

I respect that you find it complicated, but it is how the coordinate system of canvas works. A 1x1 dot at coordinate (x, y) does not occupy the pixel at [x, y], but it is a 1x1 dot centered around the coordinate (x, y). And the whole numbers of coordinate system align with the top left corners of the pixels. Or in other words, the pixel [x, y] isn't centered round the coordinate (x, y), it is top-left-aligned at that coordinate and occupies [x, x+1) in horizontal and [y, y+1) in vertical direction.

Not a grid property, it is property of drawing paths. Grid is fortunately still the same, pixel aligned coordinate system.

The reason it works on retina displays is because retina displays have multiple IRL pixels to sub-divide virtual pixels. So if a display has a 2x2 IRL pixel grid for each virtual pixel, it can accurately show a "1 pixel width" line centered around x = 120 by illuminating the half-width subpixel columns left and right of the x = 120 line instead of having to resort to half-illuminating the full-width pixel columns.

So the proper answer is this is known antialiasing property of drawing paths.
I haven't known, always good to learn new things.
Here are the docs how drawline works and applies aliasing
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors#a_linewidth_example

Good post here Can I turn off antialiasing on an HTML <canvas> element?
If one wants to still stick to 'standard' pixel system, this is small trick to have well drawn lines on whole pixels.
context.translate(0.5, 0.5);
context.lineWidth = 1;


I think you are drawing the wrong conclusions here. Ideally, for a 100% crisp line, you would want to have an x offset of 0.5, but 0 for y. Otherwise the line-endings will be blurred. However for a horizontal line, you want the y offset but no x offset. And generally speaking, this 0.5 offset also only applies to odd widths. A linewidth of 2px would appear sharp without translation and blurry with translation.
